# How to make Android treat ImageView as if it doesn't exist when scaling ConstraintLayout in ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

I'm using an ImageView with a vector drawable as a background in my ConstraintLayout which is nested inside a ScrollView. I want this background image to be aligned vertically and horizontally with a specific widget, which I'm doing by constraining it to that widget.

The problem I'm encountering is that since the ImageView is part of the ConstraintLayout, it's adding extra space for the ImageView in the ConstraintLayout which is in turn adding more scrollable space than is necessary for the useful widgets.

Essentially, I want to be able to constrain this ImageView to a widget vertically and horizontally and have the ConstraintLayout it's in "ignore" that ImageView in regards to how the ConstraintLayout is scaled while still properly scaling for the rest of the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

or

```
imageView.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: That'll prevent it from being visible to the user. I want the UI scaling to treat it as if it's set to GONE without the visibility being affected. Basically let the ImageView go out of the parent's bounds.

Comment: @GenericUsername, In that case, you should probably post your code and an image of what you want.